# HaxeFlixel - multitouch zoom

Tags: android, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

This question is rather short: is there any way of implement multitouch camera zooming for android? Before answers like: show me your code etc etc. I don't have any code. I didnt find any solution.

So question is: does HaxeFlixel support multitouch for android / iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HaxeFlixel does support multi-touch, see [`FlxTouchManager`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/input/touch/FlxTouchManager.html) or check the [cheat sheet](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/cheat-sheet/#touch-input).

You get a list of touch points (with `x` and `y` coords in screen space and world space). You have to implement your own handling of gestures - it doesn't come with built-in pinch handling (or other gestures). But I found a nice library for gestures that you might be able to use:

https://github.com/rockswang/roxlib

Comment: i will definitely check this... i will spend some time with FLxTouchManager. Thanks